# How to make Bash loops

Tags: bash

Is there a simpler way to make Bash loops?

```
declare -a n=(1 2 8);
for i in "${n[@]}";
  do HandbrakeCLI (...) --title $i -o "$i.mp4";
done
```

Comment: You loop works. You should check with `bash -x script`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify it a bit by using the number values directly as loop arguments:

```
for i in 1 2 8
  do HandbrakeCLI (...) --title $i -o "$i.mp4"
done
```

or if you need to loop over a specific number range, use the `{n..m}` construct:

```
for i in {1..8}
  do HandbrakeCLI (...) --title $i -o "$i.mp4"
done
```

Also, in shell scripts you don't need a semicolon after expressions unless you have multiple expressions on the same line.